# Oracle Query not executing properly in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jdbc, ora-00911

I am executing a simple database query in Eclipse:

```
statement.executeUpdate(
    "INSERT INTO DBUSER(USER_ID,USERNAME,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE) 
    VALUES (3,'KUMAR','ERPDIRECT',to_date('29/08/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));"
);
```

But am getting:

> ORA-00911: invalid character error

But When am executing this query in sql*plus command line it was executing without fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the trailing semi-colon from the SQL string. It's not necessary when executing via JDBC, and may in fact be an error.